# Store results of split function in variables

Tags: shell, powershell

I have files in a directory like below:

```
first-file-name
2nd-file-name
3rd-file-name
.
.
n-file-name
```

I need to store each portion of file name in a separate variable because I want to insert these values in separate columns of table.

For this, I used the below script to get the each portion of a file name:

```
$var1=$item.BaseName.Split("-",3)[0]---------first
$var2=$item.BaseName.Split("-",3)[1]---------file
$var3=$item.BaseName.Split("-",3)[2]---------name
```

and can save these values in a variable. But the question is how can I do this for all files, if I use foreach loop then the variable values will be **overwritten**???

```
foreach(item in $items)
{
 $var1=$item.BaseName.Split("-",3)[0]---------first
 $var2=$item.BaseName.Split("-",3)[1]---------file
 $var3=$item.BaseName.Split("-",3)[2]---------name
}
```

Here, in `$items` I got the file path using `get-childitem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `PsCustomObject` with the three parts:

```
$parts = $items | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        FirstPart = $item.BaseName.Split("-",3)[0]
        SecondPart = $item.BaseName.Split("-",3)[1]
        ThirdPart = $item.BaseName.Split("-",3)[2]
    }
}
```

now `$parts` is an array of these objects so you can access them using e. g.

`$parts[0].FirstPart`

Comment: Thanku @martin, if I have very large number of files in my directory? then creating object for each file will be time consuming, is there any other way?

Comment: @NEWBI..have you _tried_ this? You might be surprised at how quick it is.

Comment: I doubt this will be an issue.

Comment: yes i have tried, it successfully runs but for small number of files, for very large numbers every time I will have to add object...

Comment: Seriously, come back with your performance requirement when this becomes an issue. It won't.

Comment: @martin I meant to say , if I have 1000 files then I have to abb objects for all these thousands files?? isn't it?

Comment: you will have to add 1000 objects. but whats your concern about that?

Comment: No, this is a generic version. you don't have to update your script,